# convert a list of data frames into a single data frame with specific column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this:

```
> list("x"=data.frame("a"=(1:3),"b"=(4:6)),"y"=data.frame("a"=(1:3),"b"=(7:9)))
$x
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

$y
  a b
1 1 7
2 2 8
3 3 9
```

And I want this:

```
a x y
1 b b
2 b b
3 b b
```

with the corresponding values of b.

someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```r
cbind(a = my_list[[1]]$a, as.data.frame(lapply(my_list, `[[`, 2)))
#>   a x y
#> 1 1 4 7
#> 2 2 5 8
#> 3 3 6 9
```

Where

```r
my_list <- list(x = data.frame(a= 1:3, b = 4:6), y = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 7:9))
```

Comment: thanks... you did it... I was breaking my head... now I have to understand it... thanks again